# Can I use kryo output on same jvm to do deep compare of instances of exact same class?

Tags: java, kryo

I have two instances of exact same class which I want to compare. I am already using kryo to serialize and send it to DB.

I was wondering, can I compare both byte[] produced by Kryo (default configuration) and determine if both are same or not?

I did run following code and it seems to be working fine. Need openion from experts.

```
private static void testKryoCompare() {

    //KryoUtil is just a utility wrapper on Kryo. Nothing special there.

    int n = 1000_000;
    long start;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        byte[] b1 = KryoUtil.serialize(job);
        job.setParam1(i+"");
        byte[] b2 = KryoUtil.serialize(job);
        if(Arrays.equals(b1, b2) == true)
            System.out.println("Should not be true: "+job.getParam1());
    }

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        job.setParam1(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        byte[] b1 = KryoUtil.serialize(job);
        byte[] b2 = KryoUtil.serialize(job);
        if(Arrays.equals(b1, b2)==false)
            System.out.println("Should not be false: "+job.getParam1());
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Both instances are of exact same class - Job.class. No structure of field change. In case if one field is List<> then one instance may have ArrayList and another may have LinkedList. Kryo output may be different in that case.

My usecase is to reduce # of network calls and ripple effect. If some calls slip through even when values are same, it is ok. Based on that I am rephrasing my question below:

**Question** : Will there be a scenario where kryo output is same even when values are different in Job.class?

Comment: What do you mean by "same"? If you have arbitrary classes, `equals` can become relatively complex, so that objects are equal even when some of their fields (and hence their Kryo format) are different. For example an `ArrayList` is `equal` to a `LinkedList` of the same elements (but probably writes different bytes to disk).

Comment: @Thilo Thanks. I got what you are saing. I have edited my question to put more context and your example and rephrased the question.